# How to set up bitbucket PR builder in Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

https://github.com/jenkinsci/bitbucket-pullrequest-builder-plugin#jenkins-pipeline
In this document, bitbucket pull request builder support pipeline job.
But I don’t know how to set ‘’trigger’’ of PR builder in pipeline , especially following part.

```
bitbucketpr(projectPath:'<BIT_BUCKET_PATH>',
```

Comment: I would recommend using https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Bitbucket+Branch+Source+Plugin instead as it does all the discovery and setup itself.